# How to change $EUID value to non-zero in the bash shell

Tags: linux, shell-script, rhel

I have a script(test1.sh) like the below and i need to run it as root because As a prerequisites, we need to install a couple of packages when it enters into this script, value $EUID should be non-zero, Could you help me to change this $EUID value

test1.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ $EUID -eq 0 ]]; then
  echo "This script must be run as nonroot user. Otherwise, couple of test 
cases will fail."
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: You have a script that must be run as root, that contains a test to complain if run as root! I am confused.

Comment: read the manual on sudoers: `man sudoers`

Answer (score 3):

Only the zsh shell supports changing effective user it. That is done by changing the value of the `$EUID` special variable which underneath calls the `setresuid()` system call. You can also set the `UID` variable which would set both the real and effective user id, or assign to `USERNAME` which would simulate a login and set the real effective uids as well as real and effective group id and list of supplementary group ids as per the system's user database.

In the bash shell, `$EUID` is read-only and reflects the value of the effective user id of the process running `bash` and cannot be changed.

In `bash`, you'd need to run a separate command such as `perl`, `zsh`, `su` `sudo` to change user ids. For instance with:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
if (( EUID == 0 )); then
  exec zsh -c 'EUID=123; exec bash -p "$0" "$@"' "$0" "$@"
  # or
  exec perl -e '$> = 123; exec @ARGV' bash -p "$0" "$@"
fi
```

Would cause the script to re-execute itself with euid 123 with the help of `zsh` to change euid.

That one only sets the effective user id. Hence the `-p` option of `bash` which otherwise doesn't like its effective uid being different from the real user id.

Chances are you'd be better of changing the real uid (`UID=123`) or even simulate a real login to be in a normal situation where uids/gids match the user database (`USERNAME=realuser`), for which you could also use `su` or `sudo`:

```
exec su realuser -c 'exec "$0" ${1+"$@"}' bash "$0" "$@"
```

(assuming the login shell of `realuser` is Bourne-like)

```
exec sudo -u realuser bash "$0" "$@"
```

(beware `sudo` may do more than just changing uids/gids though)